# Where do Tensorflow in Python store the MNIST data for its tutorial?

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I am running windows and according to the script it is stored at "/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data", however I am unable to find where this is.

The reason I am asking is because I want to change part of the output data and labels.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think tensorflow package comes with the mnist data included. If you see the code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/input_data.py) it points to another function mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py). In this file, you can see that they have mentioned that the datasets will be downloaded.

> """Functions for downloading and reading MNIST data."""

**EDIT**

The data is downloaded from [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/cvdf-datasets/mnist/) but unfortunately we can't open it from our browsers.

Comment: Okay, but where is it downloaded from? I mean it must surely be loaded in from somewhere?